# How to create a user generated list of links for different records/rows in a database that populate an html form when clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, forms

Hi I have this html form.  This form is used to collect and store user/members submitted information. It uses a database with several columns 2 of importance "user_email" & "invoice_id". In the form the "user_email" input is hidden and upon page load is equal to the the value of a logged in users provided email address on file. When a user submits multiple form submissions, multiple records with the same user_email are created in the database. So say for instance if user1 submitted 3 forms there would be 3 records/rows in my database all with their "user_email" column with the same email.

I'm trying to figure out how to create a user generated list of links that will populate a form using data fetched from a database when clicked on.

Here's the best way I can explain what scenario I'm trying to make possible...

**1)Search & fetch the data for every record/row in a database table where the "user_email" column value matches the value of a sample_form1 input name: "user_email".**

```
<form action="xxx.php" id="sample_form1" name"sample_form1" method="post">


<input type="hidden" id="user_email" name="user_email" value="xxx@email.com">
<input type="text" id="invoice_id" name="invoice_id">
<input type="text" id="other1" name="other1">
<input type="text" id="other2" name="other2">

<input type="submit" value="Submit">


</form>
```

**2)Generate a list of links for each found record each one link corresponding to a different record/row found, using the value of the "invoice_id" column as the generated link's label/text.**

```
EXAMPLE:
Click here to view InvoiceID#001
Click here to view InvoiceID#002
Click here to view InvoiceID#003
```

**3)Populate sample_form1 with the fetched data when a generated link is clicked.**

Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

*1)Search & fetch the data for every record/row in a database table where the "user_email" column value matches the value of a sample_form1 input name: "user_email".*

```
$command = "SELECT invoice_id, user_email FROM tableName WHERE user_email = '$user_email'";
```

*2)Generate a list of links for each found record each one link corresponding to a different record/row found, using the value of the "invoice_id" column as the generated link's label/text.*
I didn't quite get you but

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
{
    echo '<a href="page.php?id="' . $row['invoice_id'] . '">Click here to see InvoiceID #' . $row['invoice_id'] . '</a>';
}
```

*3)Populate sample_form1 with the fetched data when a generated link is clicked.*

What do you want? Just get the data from the POST request?

```
<?php // xxx.php

// if form is submitted through the POST
if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == "POST")
{
    // Get required fields
    $user_email;
    $invoice_id;
    $other1;
    $other2;

    if (isset($_POST['user_email']) && $_POST['user_email'] != "")
        $user_email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['user_email']);

    if (isset($_POST['invoice_id']) && $_POST['invoice_id'] != "")
        $invoice_id = htmlspecialchars($_POST['invoice_id']);

    // Do same with $other1 and $other2

    // Now you have to open a connection with DB and put the data
}

?>
```